# Stop a thread and release the lock in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `ServerState` object:

```
public class ServerState {
    public static final LOCK = new ReentrantLock();
    public static Map<String, Object> states = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Thread A:

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ServerState.LOCK.lock();
        // do some dirty work
        ServerState.LOCK.unlock();
    }
}
```

My question is: when thread A has acquired the lock and is doing some dirty work, thread B wants to terminate A immediately but want it release the lock before its terminate, how can I achieve this? I am not looking for use a flag to indicate whether the thread is terminated like this:

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {
    volatile boolean isFinished = false;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!isFinished) {
            ServerState.LOCK.lock();
            // do some dirty work
            ServerState.LOCK.unlock();
        }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to terminate the thread and release the lock WITHOUT proceeding to the next iteration. Is is possible to do it in Java?

Comment: Put `ServerState.LOCK.unlock();` in a `finally` block.  See [the ReentrantLock documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) for an example.

Comment: You want to terminate thread A and release the lock while it's doing the dirty work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes, it is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @DiLuo Then what's the point of holding the lock? If you aren't going to modify the state, why hold the lock?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh sorry for the missing information. Actually during the dirty work, the threads are modifying a shared state.

Comment: @DiLuo Then if you terminate the thread and release the lock, it can leave the shared state in an in-between state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use thread [interruption mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).
If you want to interrupt on `LOCK` acquiring, you should use `LOCK.lockInterruptibly()` instead of `LOCK.lock()`:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
  @Override
  void run() {
    try {
      LOCK.lockInterruptibly();
      System.out.println("work");
      LOCK.unlock();
    } catch (InterruptedException ier) {
      this.interrupt()
    }
  }
};
```

Then, to stop `thread1` just call

```
thread1.interrupt();
```

from another thread.

Also I'd suggest to move actual logic from `Thread` to `Runnable`:

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread(
  new Runnable() {
    @Override
    void run() {
      try {
        LOCK.lockInterruptibly();
        System.out.println("work");
        LOCK.unlock();
      } catch (InterruptedException ier) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
      }
    }
  }
);
```